# EJB 2.1 ClasscastException

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-2.x

Below is my code

```
Properties localProperties = new Properties();
      localProperties.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
      localProperties.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
      localProperties.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
      localProperties.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
      localProperties.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
      InitialContext localInitialContext = new InitialContext(localProperties);
      SanityAutomationAvailabilityMain localSanityAutomationAvailabilityMain = (SanityAutomationAvailabilityMain)localInitialContext.lookup("ejb/com/cw/wad/sanity/ejb/session/interfaces/SanityAutomationAvailabilityMain");
```

I am getting a classcastexception with the above code. Any idea as to what I may be doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Add the **full stack trace** to your question.

Comment: What is InitialContext ? What do you expect from us ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to cast to (SanityAutomationAvailabilityMain) and you get a classcastexception, then whatever type the value you are trying to cast is, is not compatible with SanityAutomationAvailabilityMain.